# How to swap between array and pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

I am trying to swap between array and pointer in c++

My code is as the following :

```
void foo(int* a, int* b);
void main()
{
  int *a = NULL;
  int b[6]={2,3,5,6};
  foo(a,b);
}

void foo(int* a, int b[])
{
  int * c;
  c=a;
  a=b;
  b=c;
}
```

While I return out from the Method nothing changed ,

within the method everything work fin but when the method return nothing change.

my question is:

A) what is my mistake.?
B) How should I fix it.

Comment: If your book or professor taught you `void main()`, it's time to swap *that* one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mistake is that you assume arrays are pointers. They are not. They can decay to pointers.

You can't change `b`, but you can change `a`, by passing it by reference:

```
void foo(int*& a, int b[])
{
  int * c;
  c=a;
  a=b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `b` is allocated. But you can't transfer this "being allocated" property of an array to a pointer. You can allocate a pointer (by using `malloc` or `new`) but you can't de-allocate an array. So I'm afraid what you want to do isn't possible.

If all you want to do is exchange the contents of `a` and `b`, you'll have to do that the hard way (physically copy each value, or `memcpy` for the whole array at once), but you can't simply change the array in such a way that its address changes to that of `a`.

(Obligatory remark: since you tagged your question `c++`, you should use vectors.)